# NodeJS & Typescript - Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using Node.js and Typescript to get the data from rest api. I am alway getting an error unexpected end of JSON input. Whats wrong with my code?

I have stringify my code and with http requester it is working.

My json input looks like:

```
 {"json-input":{"handler":"getContent","image":true,"video":false,"text":false,"source":"1","lage":"testlage1"}}
```

**My code**

```
api.post("/getData", (req: Request, res: any, next: NextFunction) => {
    let getDataUrl = "restapiexample/?async";
    console.log(getDataUrl)


      let filter_data:any ={}
      delete req.body['keyId'];
      filter_data['json-input'] = req.body;

      let jsstringData = JSON.stringify(filter_data);
    console.log('###################################')
      console.log(jsstringData)
    console.log('###################################')

    request.post(
        {
            url : getDataUrl,
            form:jsstringData,
            headers : {
                "Authorization" : auth
            }
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
          if (error){
            console.log("There was an error:", error);
          } else {
            console.log("Request posted successfully!", JSON.parse(body));
          }


            // res.send(jsonData.jobs[0].id)
        }
    );
    });
```

**Error**

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input [1]     at Object.parse
>   (native) [1]     at Request._callback
>   (/home/tony/Desktop/ng2KnimeUI/dist/server/routes/api.js:49:62) [1] 
>   at Request.self.callback
>   (/home/tony/Desktop/ng2KnimeUI/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
>   [1]     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) [1]     at Request.emit
>   (events.js:191:7) [1]     at Request.
>   (/home/tony/Desktop/ng2KnimeUI/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
>   [1]     at emitOne (events.js:96:13) [1]     at Request.emit
>   (events.js:188:7) [1]     at IncomingMessage.
>   (/home/tony/Desktop/ng2KnimeUI/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
>   [1]     at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)

Comment: can you add the exact error to your post above?  It would be helpful to see any additional error syntax.  Also, does the error occur when you attempt to start your API service, or when you send a POST trigger to the server?

Comment: that and where within the provided code said error occured?

Comment: I agree with @KevinB, now we need to know which line from the code above is line `49` inside the `api.js` script.  BTW the input JSON looks well formed, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: In my compiled js file this is line 49) console.log("Request posted successfully!", JSON.parse(body));

Comment: Ok.  Then can you `console.log(body);` right before line `49` in your code, and show it in your post above?

Comment: I am getting nothing. It is empty

Comment: Well then I suggest you work on understanding why your `body` variable is empty.  That is the reason why your `JSON.parse(body)` line is failing.  Research the `request.post` callback more to understand what should be found in the arguments

Comment: ok thanks for your help. Well I am passing the json object into form. I rename form into json and try it again. If I sent it with form the content-type is url-encoded and I think this could be the reason.